# What is the difference between ' ' and " " comparison?

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox, which I need to validate against the its value is empty or not.

Should I compare the value with ' ' or " " ?

Answer (score 2):

it won't matter; for example, 'hello' and "hello" represent the same string.

```
> 'hello' === "hello"
true
```